Docker renders server inaccessible when starting
Docker on Centos 7, using Portainer to manage  containers. I created a sonarqube container from YML. When I deployed the "stack" I never had and answer.
Starting docker from console with: systemcl start docker.service, the server becomes inaccessible and needs to be restarted.
Checking logs I found /var/log/firewalld with this output:
2024-03-25 16:11:54 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D PREROUTING' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).

2024-03-25 16:11:54 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).

2024-03-25 16:11:54 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -F DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

2024-03-25 16:11:54 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -X DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

2024-03-25 16:11:55 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

2024-03-25 16:11:55 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

2024-03-25 16:11:55 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

2024-03-25 16:11:55 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

I'm trying to start the docker service without starting the container automatically.
Any advice to solve my problem?

When I deployed the "stack" I never had and answer. you should investigate that instead of starting the container.
